# Selenium 4 alpha Maven dependency still downlaoding 3.1.4 sources

Tags: java, selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver, selenium4

I have a Selenium-Java project that I want to update to Selenium 4 Alpha 6.

I have removed previous POM references to all selenium dependencies and have even hard set the desired version number.

No suitable constructor errors are thrown for this package on compilation - my new Selenium is not being used as the new functionality is not available (same site cookie support).

When I review the maven tab in intellij it shows many old source:
[image]

My project classes still open up the (decompiled) Selenium 3 classes when I find definitions.

My Maven POM changes:
[image]
Also I have removed a top level reference to selenium-api which I think is a dependency of the primary anyway...I've also tried using the systemPath attribute to force use of trhe JAR I downloaded but made no difference.

Can anyone advise how to 'force' the update?

Comment: Show us the whole POM.

Comment: That maven pom should fail on command line cause it contains two version tags ...furthermore why using the systemPath ? does not make sense... The selenium dependency is available on central: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/4.0.0-alpha-6/jar

Comment: @JFabianMeier - I can't very easily...its massive..Here is the dependecies section:

Comment: @khmarbaise - I just tried that as a possible workaround after failing..

Comment: @JFabianMeier - Dependencies: https://pastebin.pl/view/9c047aa2

Comment: @khmarbaise - it is a picture of the diff the previous line is the previous version number

Comment: It is hard to tell without the POM, but I guess you have some BOM in your `<dependencyManagement>` that overrides transitive versions.

Comment: @JFabianMeier - OK my redacted POM uploaded to https://pastebin.pl/view/a1276f9d note I've removed some references to work specific library stuff that is just independent stuff that shouldn't impact...

Comment: Where is the dependencyManagement?

Comment: Its doesn't have a dependencyManagement tag. This is a single pom project.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium 4 is alpha version they did not release valid selenium 4 there are issues in the alpha version so you need wait for the original release from selenium Hq

Comment: Its been out for ages now though and have 6 iterations of said Alpha